# The intersection of open balls that center in $S$ and whose boundaries pass through $x$ is empty iff $x$ is in the closed convex hull of $S$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, normed-spaces, convex-hulls

Suppose $\left(V,\left\|\cdot\right\|\right)$ is a strictly convex normed space,
$S\subseteq V$ and $x\in V$.
Then, iff $x$ is in the closed convex hull of $S$, we have
$$\bigcap_{a\in S}B\!\left(a,\left\|x-a\right\|\right)=\varnothing,$$
where $B$ denotes open balls. Is this true? How to prove or construct a counterexample?

I can easily prove this when $S$ consists of two distinct points.
It also seems correct when $S$ are discrete points in the Euclidean plane.
I wonder whether it can be generalized to more general $V$ and $S$.

For the case when $x$ is not in the closed convex hull of S,
here is my idea to prove that there is some point $y$ in the intersection of the open balls.
There exists a closed half-space $Y$ of $V$ such that $S$ and $x$ are separated by it
and that $S$ does not contain a sequence that approaches any point in $Y$.
By Riesz's lemma, we can choose a point $y$ in $Y$ whose distance to $x$ is arbitrarily close to the distance $d$ from $x$ to $Y$.
My idea is to prove that, when $\left\|y-x\right\|$ is small enough (close enough to $d$),
we have $\left\|y - a\right\|<\left\|x - a\right\|$ for any $a\in S$,
then $y$ is a point in the intersection of the open balls.
However I do not know how to proceed.

For the case when $x$ is in the closed convex hull of $S$,
I currently do not have any idea.